# Using AlphaVantage For Japan/Shanghai/Hong Kong/Shenzhen stock exchange data?

Tags: equities, data, market-data

Can I use AlphaVantage to pull data from Asian stock markets? I've been able to do it for others such as the London stock exchange, India stock exchange, Australian stock exchange etc. but haven't got it working for Japan/Shanghai/Hong Kong/Shenzhen stock exchanges. Do they have data for these? And if so, what are the stock exchange codes to feed into the URL?

I've tried for example the following (for the Tokyo stock exchange, looking up symbol 4446):

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=TYO.4446&apikey=myapikey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the examples just got tested.  They all work for me with my API key.  Just swap in your API key below, and you should be all set.

**For Tokyo:**

Sony: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=6758.T&apikey=your_api_key

Hitachi: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=6501.T&apikey=your_api_key

**For Hong Kong:**

Tsingtao Brewery: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=0168.HK&apikey=your_api_key

**For Shanghai:**

Agricultural Bank of China: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=601288.SS&apikey=your_api_key

**For Shenzhen:**

Huawen Media Group: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=000793.SZ&apikey=your_api_key

Comment: HK support seems to be dropped.

Comment: Japan also dropped.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. Any workarounds? Does anyone know another API for eastern stock data?

Answer (score 2):

The problem: you do not know the correct ticker for stocks listed on multiple exchanges.

The solution: Use the [search endpoint](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#symbolsearch) to find the ticker.

Let's say we want to find the correct ticker for Tsingtao Brewery listed in Hong Kong and Shanghai:

1. Search for the ticker: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=tsingtao+brewery&apikey=my-api-key
2. From the results, we see that the correct ticker is `0168.HKG` for Hong Kong, and `600600.SHH` for Shanghai.

Comment: It seems that they no longer return Hong Kong ticker.

Comment: Not only hongkong is missing or not working.. Also some German stocks are not working and it is not related to the exchange (for .DEX some are working and some not)

Answer (score 2):

I tried with AlphaVantage in early 2020 for international stock data. The quality is poor vs the US data. (ok, if you are just trading the biggest 20 stocks in the market, it is probably fine. But if you want to go mid to small cap....). In fact, the errors that I have spotted are exactly the same as the errors pulled from yahoo finance. They might have or have not changed their data source since. But if not, I suspect they just get the (international stocks) data from yahoo. So if you are paying them, might as well get it for free from yahoo.

Comment: There have been some allegations that AlphaVantage is not authorized to redistribute data: https://www.reddit.com/r/algotrading/comments/hnxoy6/beware_alphavantage_is_not_a_licensed_provider/